# How do I check if the user specified a channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a say command in a Discord bot where you specify a channel to send the message, and if you don't specify a channel it will send everything after the command(args 1+), otherwise it will send everything after the channel specified(args 2+)

```
if(command === `${prefix}say`) {
    if(!message.member.roles.has(`337402636015894528`)) return;
    msg = args.slice(2).join(" ");
    let channel = message.mentions.channels.first() || message.guild.channels.find("name", args[1]) || message.channel;
    message.delete();
    channel.send(msg);
}
```

This is the code I have, but the problem is that want to check if the user specified a channel, and if not, set msg equal to args.slice(1).join(" "), but I have no idea how to check if the user specified a channel. Does anybody know how? Thanks in advance.

I figured out the solution, thank you all for your help.

```
let channel = message.mentions.channels.first() || message.guild.channels.find("name", args[1]);
if(!channel) { 
    channel = message.channel;
    msg = args.slice(1).join(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tagging a channel in a message looks like this
`<#channelid>`
Example:
`<#316648154927938738>`
So you can match against that.

Alternatively, the api does return mentioned channels in the [message object](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#message-object).
So that can be used as well.
I haven't used discord.js, but I'm sure they offer a way of accessing that quite easily.

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried to use this in an if statement
`if(!channel === message.mentions.channels.first() || message.guild.channels.find("name", args[1])) msg = args.slice(1).join(" ");`
but the issue with that is that if the user just says the channel name instead of tagging it, the channel name appears in the bots message. This will be my solution for now, and I may have to remove the ability to type the name instead of tagging.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply check if the args are a number with

```
if(isNaN(args[0])) {
// stuff
}
```